Space break using \ error on gb4e's end of xlist
I have this following tex document, where I want to input a space break right after the gb4e xlist ends:
%okegas yuk bisa yuk

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex[{\bf (RU)}]{\lb{K}\lb{FN}\?{\it Путин}]\lb{FV}\?{\it опроверг}\lb{FN}\lb{N}\?{\it дискриминацию}]\lb{N.ADJ}\?{\it геев}]\lb{FP}\lb{P}\?{\it в}]\lb{FN}\?{\it России}]]]]] }

\ex{Uraian sintaksis (a) dan urutan struktur kalimat (b)}
 \begin{xlist}
 \ex[{\bf (ID)}]{\lb{K} \lb{FN} Putin]\lb{FV} membantah\lb{FN}\lb{N}diskriminasi\textsc{-aku}]\lb{N.PAR}gay\textsc{-jam.gen}] \lb{FP} \lb{P}di]\lb{FN}Rusia\textsc{-prep}]]]]] }
 \ex[{\bf (ID)}]{\lb{FN\textsc{-s}} Putin] \lb{FV\textsc{-pred}} membantah] \lb{FN\textsc{-obj}} diskriminasi gay] \lb{KET} di Rusia]}
 \end{xlist}

\end{exe}

\noindent {\LARGE \bf Pohon uraian sintaksis}

\end{document}

The typeset of the tex document:

Currently, there is no space break between the xlist of the gb4e and the "Uraian pohon sintaksis" text thumbnail. I'd like to add space for that, so I used the \ argument:
\ex[{\bf (RU)}]{\lb{K}\lb{FN}\?{\it Путин}]\lb{FV}\?{\it опроверг}\lb{FN}\lb{N}\?{\it дискриминацию}]\lb{N.ADJ}\?{\it геев}]\lb{FP}\lb{P}\?{\it в}]\lb{FN}\?{\it России}]]]]] }

\ex{Uraian sintaksis (a) dan urutan struktur kalimat (b)}
 \begin{xlist}
 \ex[{\bf (ID)}]{\lb{K} \lb{FN} Putin]\lb{FV} membantah\lb{FN}\lb{N}diskriminasi\textsc{-aku}]\lb{N.PAR}gay\textsc{-jam.gen}] \lb{FP} \lb{P}di]\lb{FN}Rusia\textsc{-prep}]]]]] }
 \ex[{\bf (ID)}]{\lb{FN\textsc{-s}} Putin] \lb{FV\textsc{-pred}} membantah] \lb{FN\textsc{-obj}} diskriminasi gay] \lb{KET} di Rusia]} \\\ % The argument
 \end{xlist}

However, I retrieved this following error:
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/l
ocal/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc}]
Overfull \hbox (37.69264pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 89--89
[]$[][] $$[][] $\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Putin]$[][] $membantah$[][] $$[][] $diskriminas
i\OT1/cmr/m/sc/10 -aku\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ]$[][] $gay\OT1/cmr/m/sc/10 -jam.gen\OT1/
cmr/m/n/10 ] $[][] $$[][] $di]$[][] $Rusia\OT1/cmr/m/sc/10 -prep\OT1/cmr/m/n/10
 ]]]]] 

./glosa.tex:90: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.90 ... diskriminasi gay] \lb{KET} di Rusia]} \\\
                                                  
? 

But the weird thing is, the space break is there!

What is the possible cause of this error reading? And how I can avoid it?

Do not use \noindent {\LARGE \bf Pohon uraian sintaksis}. Use a semantic command like \section{Pohon uraian sintaksis}. Such commands then also take care about spaces.

It works, but also it introduces number to the left of the text, which I dont want. I ended up using \vspace{4mm} command @UlrikeFischer

You can use \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} to suppress all numbering. Or use \section*{Pohon}. Or use some package like titlesec to redefine your sectioning command. The main point it to use a semantic command that you can style in the preamble and not to use lots manual formatting that have no connection to the structure of your document.

Thanks for the input! @UlrikeFischer
